# How to bind SP list to Spfx extension as dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx-extensions, dropdown

I have a SP List with 5 items and Url to it. So now I would like to add this SP list as dropdown to SPFX extension. I was wondering how to achieve this as I know how to add as an WebPart but not to SPFX extn.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, we can bind dropdown list from a SharePoint Online list using `react` and `PnP` in the SharePoint Framework (SPFx). Please refer to the following document to bind dropdown list from SharePoint list:

https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/spfx-bind-dropdown-list-from-sharepoint-list/

*Note: Microsoft is providing this information as a convenience to you. The sites are not controlled by Microsoft. Microsoft cannot make any representations regarding the quality, safety, or suitability of any software or information found there. Please make sure that you completely understand the risk before retrieving any suggestions from the above link.*

Hope it can help you. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, which means it is possible to bind them in spfx extension